# How to create a custom datetime in UTC and convert it into a different timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have a scheduler that runs every day at 2PM, 4PM, 6PM UTC. I need to convert these time to Australia/Melbourne timezone and compare it with the current australian time. How can I achieve this conversion as any moment/vanilla JS date methods requires a DATE too to deal with time

Comment: @Yogi, thanks the above link helped